# US Residential Mailing Addresses Databases

Tags: usa, geospatial, api, address

What I'm looking for I can almost guarantee I won't find openly available anywhere but I'll try anyway.

Simply, I'm looking for a list of residential addresses of a given county or city/municipality in the USA for personal use. I can't find anything like this without shelling out huge bucks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- OpenAddresses.io does not have nearly 100% coverage but you may get lucky: http://results.openaddresses.io/
- Open Street Map ("OSM") is another potential source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121266/extracting-list-of-addresses-in-particular-region-from-openstreetmap-osm-data
- One less expensive option *may* be to buy voter registration lists from jurisdictions which will have less coverage but also be less expensive than traditional marketing lists, it seems.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Unfortunately the area I need is not covered by `OpenAddresses.io` so I'm going to install a `Postgres` database with `postgis` extension support on my server with an `osm` extract of the region I need using `download.bbbike.org`. I think I'm on the right track.

Comment: If openaddresses.io doesn't have data for the area,  but you find an open, public source for address data in that area, think about creating a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why it is not so easy to find such a data. Each state has its own rules for operating data like that. Most data out there comes from elections and can be floating around for dirt cheap if it is old.

Whoever, be very careful if you decide to use such data. It comes heavy regulated. See [voter list](https://walklists.com/terms) regulations.

Another source could be geocoding [databases/census data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TIGER). Each state again is listed separately.

Third option is to buy consumer data. It has much more than just addresses. and price is not cheap as you said.

I am a data vendor myself and sell voter and consumer data. However, I am very skeptical when someone ask for huge amount of data for personal use.

The amount of data is very hard to operate if you are not technical enough as the volumes are big. Databases require maintenance and the most important thing: data gets old the day you obtain it.

So, eventually when you buy old data, if you planing to send bulk mail, you will waste much more for invalid addresses than buying the right data for initial higher price.

Disclaimer: I founded [Batch Geocoding](https://csv2geo.com) platform CSV2GEO and [Voter/Consumer online data](https://walklists.com)  Walk Lists.